# JTable and JButton inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a JPanel with many components on it. He is a part of the main frame. I used GridBagLayout on him for placing components and it all works great.
In one part of that JPanel I placed JScrillingPane with another JPanel (p2). I need to place JTable (extended one by my own) and JButton on p2 one beyond second one. I used several Layouts on p2 but my extended JTable ALWAYS gets too much wide. It must not pass JScrollPane (or p2 border, whatever). When I put only JButton on p2, all works fine, but with table, all goes really bad.

So, the order of components is: JPanel with GridBagLayout, JScrollPane, JPanel with any layout, JButton and JTable at last level.

What I need to look for or whatever? I didnt post the code because it is very long and will take too much space on this page.

P.S. I know there are similar questions, but I really didnt find anything helpfull for me.I searched for hours already.

Comment: Maybe use an additional `JPanel` dedicated to your table might help.

Comment: @TanmayPatil Tried. Not helpping :/

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [short, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on the problem you describe.